# How to extract lines that start with the word "Call: " using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is the code I tried

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    extractEmail(richTextBox1.Text);            
    richTextBox2.Lines = emails.ToArray();                      
}

public void extractEmail(String htmlDoc)
{

    Regex exp = new Regex("^Call:(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matchCollection = exp.Matches(htmlDoc);
    foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
    {
        if (!emails.Contains(m.Value))
            emails.Add(m.Value);
    }
}
```

I tried many alternatives but it is not working. I can find empty lines using the code

```
"^(.*)"
```

But I am unable to extract lines that starts with Call:

Thanks in advance.

Edit---

Sample Input:

```
Call: (044) 43593164

asdfasdf

adsfadsf

Call: (044) 43593164
asdfadf
```

Output I am getting:

None. no error no output.

Edit---

Found the Answer thanks to Nico Schertler

```
 Regex exp = new Regex("^Call:(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        MatchCollection matchCollection = exp.Matches(htmlDoc);
        foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
        {
            if (!emails.Contains(m.Value))
                emails.Add(m.Value);

        }
        richTextBox2.Lines = emails.ToArray();
```

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: Seems you tried to extract from html, [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the tool to help you to do this

Comment: Please explain what kind of example you like. I used the above code to extract emails, phone number, etc. But I am unable to extract an entire line starting with the word "Call:". Thanks for your time.

Comment: and example of the input and the output expected

Comment: I am not extracting from html, its a document, I didn't change the variable names because its for my personal use. Also does String.Startswith extracts more than one line starting with "Call:". Thanks!

Comment: I added an example, thanks!

Comment: @SecretSecret - No, `String.Startswith` will only match one line at a time - since you have a single string, I removed the comment.  If you had a List of strings (or an array of strings), say from a file you read, then you could loop through the list/array and test each line with `String.Startswith`.

Comment: @SecretSecret - Is `RichTextBox1` a multiline RichTextBox?  I'm guessing not since you're reading the `Text` property rather than `Lines`, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: Try to set `RegexOptions.Multiline`. This will allow the `^` character to match the beginning of any line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression will match all lines which start with `Call:`

Regex: `^Call:\s+.*`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
Call: (044) 43593164
asdfasdf
adsfadsf
Call: (044) 43593164
asdfadf
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"^Call:\s+.*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => Call: (044) 43593164
[1] => Call: (044) 43593164
```